# Flutter - FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/path' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1) on ios

Tags: ios, flutter

I am using multi_image_picker:4.5.9 on ios, when i pick up an image and get the path of the file,i want to upload this file to server,but the error comes out.

Comment: Hello and thank you for asking the question here on stackoverflow. Could you add some code you wrote? Also, it is better to add an error description into the question details rather in title.

Answer (score 2):

This error might happened because the file might not be existed yet. so you should check if the file existed or not before opening it.

use `file.existsSync()` before opening it.

Comment: Please explain.